# Orthogonality of DFT Matrix

Tags: matrices, fourier-transform, orthogonal-matrices

I am trying to proof that the DFT matrix is orthogonal but i stucked. I just know to proof the orthogonality of two vectors, not a single matrix. How can we proof that the DFT matrix is orthogonal? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1708143/prove-that-the-dft-matrix-is-unitary or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2413218/proof-of-orthonormality-of-basis-of-dft

Comment: Sir, I want to see that the matrix is orthogonal not the orthonormality of basis functions. Thanks.